# Menu path issue in DRUPAL 7

Tags: drupal, hook-menu

I have a site and it was perfectly. I have moved the site on a new server. Now everything working perfectly except new menu path.

Example : I have created a view with page display and I have created a path 'album'. But the path shows page not found error. Also , I couldnt create any custom path by using the hook_menu. All existing paths are working . I couldnt create new path on the site. This is the issue .

Please help me to debug this issue

Comment: Can you provide some code as well..?

Comment: Its not relating to code. The system doesnt build new menu path. This is the issue.

Comment: Make sure to correctly set $base_url in settings.php.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try clearing the drupal menu cache?